# NDSolve boundary query / Extracting values from solution

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I have a function $O_{2}$ with boundary conditions $O_{2}(r_{o}) = p_{o} $ and $O_{2}(g) =  O_{2}'(g) = 0$. I plot it using the solver code below;

```
a = 5*10^-7;
po = 100;
omega = 3.0318*10^7;
ro = 5*10^-6;
Do2 = 2*10^-9;
ko = 1;
con = (a*omega)/(Do2);
g = 110*10^-6;

s = NDSolve[{D[r*O2'[r], r] - con*r*((O2[r])/(O2[r] + ko)) == 0, 
O2'[g] == 0, O2[ro] == po}, O2, {r, ro, g}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {O2[g] == 0, O2'[g] == 0}}];

Af = Plot[Evaluate[{(O2[r]) /. s}], {r, ro, g}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Solution"}]]
```

This produces the following solution;

[image: 110 solution]

Now, we can see that at $g$, the solution doesn't reach zero. Let's choose a different $g$ - let's say $g = 130 \cdot 10^-6$ - then we get the solution;

[image: 130 image]

Which does indeed seem to hit zero. I'm trying to find the approximate value of $g$ such that the initial conditions are satisfied and $O_{2}(g) = 0$ - So I have two questions;

(1) Is there a automated method of doing this such that the "ideal" value of $g$ is found to satisfy the equation?

(2) Is there a way I can get or extort the solution value at a point of my choosing? For example, is I want to find $O_{2}(g/2)$ or $O_{2}(g)$ , what would I have to enter it? I have, for example, tried

```
s[g/2]
```

and this merely tells me the solution is an interpolating function, not the specific value of it. All advice welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: dont know why this old question got bumped - but you do know that `StartingInitialConditions` is basically an initital guess and your "boundary condition" `O2'[g]=0` isn't specified, and in fact cant be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to solve the problem by slightly moving away from $r=g$, i.e. by using regulated initial conditions.

In order to find these initial conditions, you could for instance solve your equations perturbatively around $r=g$. The first order correction will probably suffice. Then, you impose your initial conditions at $r=g-\delta g$ rather than $r=g$, where you take $\delta g>0$ small but finite.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I think the problem is the equation is not very stable and gets upset rather easily, which is why I've deployed the shooting method. But I like your idea, so will try to implement that now!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an answer to at least the 2nd part of my question;

To extract values from the NDSolve output, we define the output as a function;

```
fun = O2 /. First[s]
```

and then simply use it like any function, so for example;

```
 fun[ro]
```

returns the initial value of 100....